# 2010: How to get Item-ID in SharePoint view? {@ID} gives GUID, not ID

Tags: 2010, xslt, view

In a view of a custom list, I want to add a Script call to a link which opens a custom application page inside a model dialog. The JS function needs the current Item ID as a  parameter, so I create the link inside the view like this:

```
<a href="javascript:openDialog({@ID})">
```

but {@ID} results to a GUID, but I just need the content of the ID column of the list item. How do I get that?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure? afaik, @ID is the ID indeed

Answer (score 2):

How to pass list item Id in Xsl for List View:

```
<a>
    <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript:openDialog(<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ID"/>);</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Title"/>
</a>
```

### Example of customizing field in SharePoint 2010

The following template

```
  <xsl:template name="FieldRef_printTableCell_EcbAllowed.Details" match="FieldRef[@Name='Details']" mode="printTableCellEcbAllowed" ddwrt:dvt_mode="body" >
    <xsl:param name="thisNode" select="."/>
    <td>
      <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="href">javascript:openDialog(<xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@ID"/>);</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:value-of select="$thisNode/@Title"/>
      </a>
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
```

renders field named `Details` as:

```
<td class="ms-vb-lastCell"><a href="javascript:openDialog([Item Id]);">[Title]</a></td>
```

References

[`<xsl:attribute>` Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256165%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried <img src="somepath" OnClick= "openTTDialog('{$this/@ID}')" /> which results to a GUID too. How does that translate to that strange xsl:attribute syntax you use?

Comment: The answer has been updated to make it more clear

Answer (score 0):

If you use the internal name "ows_ID" (instead of "ID") does that work?

I created a test custom list and examined the schema of the list using powershell (see image).

After getting a reference to the list in $list, I was able to get at the ID (which was "1" and not a GUID) like this:

```
$items = $list.items
$item  = $item[0]
$item["ows_ID"]
```

[image]